# MongoDB and Cosmos DB key error collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, azure, express, mongoose-schema

I'm trying to create my first MongoDB app with Express & Angular & Azure Cosmos DB.
Here is my js files:

**hero.model.js**

```
 const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
    const heroSchema = new Schema({
    id: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
      unique: true
    },
    name: String
    }, {
    collection: 'Heroes'
    })
    const Hero = mongoose.model('Hero', heroSchema);
    module.exports = Hero;
```

**mongo.js**

```
 const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
    const env = require('./env/environment');
    const mongoUri = 
    mongodb:`${env.accountName}:${env.key}@${env.accountName}
    .documents.azure.com:10255/?ssl=true`
    function connect() {
    mongoose.set('debug', true);
    return mongoose.connect(mongoUri)
    }
    module.exports = {
    connect,
    mongoose
    };
```

**index.js**

```
   const express = require('express');
    const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    const path = require('path');
    const routes = require('./routes');
    const root = './';
    const port = process.env.PORT || '3000';
    const app = express();
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
    app.use(express.static(path.join(root, 'docs')));
    app.use('/api', routes);
    app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile('docs/index.html', {root});
    });
```

**route.js**

```
  const express = require('express');
    const router = express.Router();
    const heroService = require('./hero.service');
    router.get('/heroes', (req, res) => {
    heroService.getHeroes(req, res);
    });
    router.post('/hero', (req, res) => {
    heroService.postHero(req, res);
    });
    router.put('/hero/:id', (req, res) => {
    heroService.putHero(req, res);
    });
    router.delete('/hero/:id', (req, res) => {
    heroService.deleteHero(req, res);
    });
    module.exports = router;
    app.listen(port, () => console.log(`API running on 
    localhost:${port}`));
```

**hero.service.js**

```
 const Hero = require('./hero.model');
    require('./mongo').connect();
    function getHeroes(req, res) {
    const docquery = Hero.find({});
    docquery
    .exec()
    .then(heroes => {
      res.status(200).json(heroes);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      res.status(500).send(error);
      return;
    });
    }
    function postHero(req, res) {
    const originalHero = {
    id: req.body.id,
    name: req.body.name
    };
    const hero = new Hero(originalHero);
    hero.save(error => {
    if (checkServerError(res, error)) return;
    res.status(201).json(hero);
    console.log('Hero created successfully!');
    });
    }
    function checkServerError(res, error) {
    if (error) {
    res.status(500).send(error);
    return error;
    }
    }
    function putHero(req, res) {
    const originalHero = {
    id: parseInt(req.params.id, 10),
    name: req.body.name
    };
    Hero.findOne({
    id: originalHero.id
    }, (error, hero) => {
    if (checkServerError(res, error)) return;
    if (!checkFound(res, hero)) return;

    hero.name = originalHero.name;
    hero.save(error => {
      if (checkServerError(res, error)) return;
      res.status(200).json(hero);
      console.log('Hero updated successfully!');
    });
    });
    }
    function deleteHero(req, res) {
    const id = parseInt(req.params.id, 10);
    Hero.findOneAndRemove({
      id: id
    })
    .then(hero => {
      if (!checkFound(res, hero)) return;
      res.status(200).json(hero);
      console.log('Hero deleted successfully!');
    })
    .catch(error => {
      if (checkServerError(res, error)) return;
    });
    }
    function checkFound(res, hero) {
    if (!hero) {
    res.status(404).send('Hero not found.');
    return;
    }
    return hero;
    }
    module.exports = {
     getHeroes,
     postHero,
     putHero,
     deleteHero
    };
```

It only works when I POST a new hero for the first time and a second time gives me an error:
E11000 duplicate key error collection: admin.Heroes Failed _id or unique key constraint.

Please help!!

Thanks.

Comment: `id` and `_id` mean the same thing in mongoose. It's the primary key in MongoDB. You appear to be always sending the same value. There's also no need to mark as `unique` in the schema, since that is "implied" for a primary key.

Comment: I check my data [
    {
        "_id": "5ad859e64deacd31b934c74f",
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Superman",
        "__v": 0
    }
]
Do I need to change Schema configuration?

Comment: I'm following the same tutorial and having the same problem.  Did you figure this out?

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while but I've encountered the same problem. The solution is avoid using the field name id, rename it to UID or something. Once you done that you have to remove the entire collection and restart.

If you are following the Microsoft CosmosDB Angular tutorial, you can clone the repo below and test it on your local.

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/angular-cosmosdb

If you are using a newer version of mongoose you have to upgrade the connection string below.

```
         //useMongoClient: true
         useNewUrlParser: true
```